# How to display the different page block tables based on the custom picklist selection in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

i wanted to show the different objects data in diffrent page block tables based on the custom picklist selection.please suggest me if there is any idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.
1. you define different section in same vf page containing your pageoblock table for different object. Make the section hidden and on the  click of picklist value make it visible.
2. you can define an different vf page  with pageblock table and render on the click of picklist value.

Comment: Hi Ajay,I have tried and not able to